# Babel - TypeError: Plugin 1 specified in "foreign" was expected to return an object when invoked but returned "boolean"

Tags: javascript, node.js, babeljs, babel-core

I upgraded to `babel-core 6.13.2` now I'm getting this error.

```
/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:120
  throw new TypeError(messages.get("pluginNotObject", loc, i, typeof obj === "undefined" ? "undefined" : (0, _typeof3.default)(obj)) + loc + i);
  ^

TypeError: Plugin 1 specified in "foreign" was expected to return an object when invoked but returned "boolean"foreign1

at Function.memoisePluginContainer (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:120:13)

at Function.normalisePlugin (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:141:32)
at /var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:181:30
at Array.map (native)
at Function.normalisePlugins (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:153:20)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:245:36)
at /var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:254:17
at /var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:342:20
at Array.map (native)
at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:305:20)
at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:253:29)
at OptionManager.init (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:383:12)
at compile (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:103:45)
at loader (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:148:14)
at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/var/www/html/kalahi-rf/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:7)
at Module.load (module.js:458:32)
```

Anyone experiencing the error? Thanks.

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "plugins": ["./server/utils/babelRelayPlugin"],
  "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        ["react-transform", {
          "transforms": [{
            "transform": "react-transform-hmr",
            "imports": ["react"],
            "locals": ["module"]
          }, {
            "transform": "react-transform-catch-errors",
            "imports": ["react", "redbox-react"]
          }]
        }]
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**babelRelayPlugin**

```
/* eslint-disable no-var, func-names, prefer-arrow-callback, global-require */
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');
var jsonFile = path.join(__dirname, '../data/schema.json');

// Read the schema.json file only if it exists, this fixed
// the problem of using babelRelayPlugin, defined in .babelrc,
// and running npm run update when the file doesn't exist
fs.access(jsonFile, fs.F_OK, function (err) {
  if (!err) module.exports = require('babel-relay-plugin')(require(jsonFile).data);
});
```

Comment: What's your babel config look like?

Comment: @loganfsmyth you mean the `.babelrc`? Please see edit :)

Comment: And what's in `./server/utils/babelRelayPlugin` ?

Comment: @loganfsmyth I added the file just now.

Comment: That usage of `fs.access` means your export value gets assigned asynchronously, potentially after Babel read the value. Either drop that, or use `accessSync`. I bet it'll work after that.

Comment: @loganfsmyth by "drop that" what do you mean? Which one should I drop?

Answer (score 0):

Your usage of `fs.access` means that your `module.exports =` line can run *after* Babel has already run and completed processing the plugin. You should either

```
module.exports = require('babel-relay-plugin')(require(jsonFile).data);
```

since it's not clear what you're trying to do. Your current approach to do nothing on error just means there's a chance Babel will run without the plugin having been initialized.

If you absolutely need the `fs.access` check, do it synchronously:

```
// Read the schema.json file only if it exists, this fixed
// the problem of using babelRelayPlugin, defined in .babelrc,
// and running npm run update when the file doesn't exist
try {
  fs.accessSync(jsonFile, fs.F_OK);

  module.exports = require('babel-relay-plugin')(require(jsonFile).data);
} catch(e) {}
```

Comment: No changes :( the problem still exist.